# how can i throw a data from my PostgreSQL to URL?

Tags: php

i know my Title Question is kinda messed up i don't know how should i say it properly..
im having trouble using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] how can i put a data to the URL and retrieve it using $_Get[''] for editing.
here's my code's:

```
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{

    if($_POST['Submit'] == "Search" )
    {

        $sql = "SELECT tbl_item.*, tbl_ingredient.brandname, tbl_misc.size , tbl_misc.color
                FROM (tbl_item LEFT JOIN tbl_ingredient ON tbl_item.itemid = tbl_ingredient.itemid) LEFT JOIN tbl_misc ON tbl_item.itemid = tbl_misc.itemid Where tbl_item.itemid = ". $_POST['Item'];
    }
    echo "<table width='990' height='69' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo  "<td width='150' height='23'><div align='center'>Item Name</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='125'><div align='center'>High Quantity Threshold</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='125'><div align='center'>Low Quantity Threshold</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='127'><div align='center'>Quantity per unit</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='72'><div align='center'>Item Type</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='37'><div align='center'>Description</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='94'><div align='center'>Brand Name</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='60'><div align='center'>Size</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='100'><div align='center'>Color</div></td>";
    echo   "<td width='55'><div align='center'>Action</div></td>";
    echo   "</tr>";

    $holder = pg_query($sql);

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($holder, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC))
        {
        $itemid = $row['itemid'];               
        $itemname = $row['itemname'];
        $highqntythreshold = $row['highqntythreshold'];
        $lowqntythreshold = $row['lowqntythreshold'];
        $qpunit = $row['qntyperunit'];
        $itemtype = $row['itemtype'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $brandname = $row['brandname'];
        $size = $row['size'];
        $color = $row['color'];

echo "<tr align='center' bgcolor = ''>";
echo "<td height='23'><div align='center'>".$itemname."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$highqntythreshold."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$lowqntythreshold."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$qpunit."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$itemtype."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$description."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$brandname."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$size."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'>".$color."</div></td>";
echo "<td><div align='center'><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?itemid='".$itemid."'>Edit</a></div></td>";          
echo "</tr>";

    }
}
```

when i press edit URL result:`("http://localhost/Php/CTea/UpdateItem.php?itemid=")` only.

thanks!.

Comment: @Martin E. yo dude, can u help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<td><div align='center'><a href='".sprintf("%s?itemid=%s", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $itemid)."'>Edit</a></div></td>";
```

the problem is a single-quote (') added right after (itemid=') you could simple remove it but its better you try the above code because its more neat.

Comment: if im gonna add itemtype= to the url how should it would look like in code?which should i insert the itemtype?

Comment: sprintf("%s?itemid=%s&itemtype=%s", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $itemid, $itemtype);